# QGIS Clip raster bands SCP QGSPointXY(): overload error

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, scp

What is the cause of this error and how do I remove it? I was trying to execute clip raster bands using coordinates.

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

TypeError: QgsPointXY(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:   overload 1: too many arguments   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'   overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'   overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'   overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'   overload 6: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\clip_bands_tab.py", line 196, in clip_bands_action
    clip_bands()
  File "C:\Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\clip_bands_tab.py", line 305, in clip_bands
    upper_left_point = cfg.util_qgis.create_qgis_point(
  File "C:\Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\util_qgis.py", line 442, in create_qgis_point
    return QgsPointXY(x, y)
TypeError: QgsPointXY(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 6: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

[image: QGIS Error]

Comment: Maybe the functions wants to get something numeric as input, but your code is sending strings?

Comment: but my input in the coordinates are integers...

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @user30184 I don't have a code. I'm just running the SCP plug-in itself.

Comment: This plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/? I tried to install it but it failed for some reason. Let's hope that somebody else can help.

Comment: Yes that's the one. Maybe it's a bug.